# How to pop to the previous viewController automatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I connected mainViewController and customTableViewController with a "push" segue. The mainViewController pass an array of data to customTableViewController in prepareForSegue. If the array is empty, customTableViewController should automatically pop back to the mainViewController.

My code looks like this:

```
    //customTableViewController.m
    - (void) viewDidload 
    {
        if (self.array.count == 0) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
        }
    }
```

But all i got is a blank and black view if the array is empty, not the mainViewController.

If i call popViewControllerAnimated manually (such as pushing a button), everything just works as i expected. So, what should i do?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use your code in `-viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`